# Regex to match all word starts with @ or # for .net

Tags: regex

is there any regex to detect word that starts with @ or # for .net?
I tried `^[@#]` but it doesn't seem to work for special character like @ or #

Comment: Do you have some example strings you're trying to match.  Little bit difficult to see where you're going wrong without them.

Comment: @wp78de I think you mean `\b[@#]\w+`

Comment: Yea, good idea: `string pattern = @"\b[@#]\w+";`

Comment: I want to pick out all variable and temptable in a sql script, so things like: 
DECLARE @abc INT -> abc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your regex `^[@#]` you match a `@` or `#` from the start of the string using `^`. You could omit the `^` and add `\w+` to match on or more word characters.

[`[@#]\w+`](https://regex101.com/r/ooGTEa/1)

`string pattern = @"[@#]\w+";`

If you want to match more than `\w+` you could also add that to a character class and add what you want to match like for example `[@#][\w+$]`.

Comment: tks, I got it now :D